# Update model with newly added field/column

Tags: python, model, field, migrate, peewee

Python app, using peewee to work with SQLite databases.

I have this model containing one field:

```
class RepUser(Model):
    user = BigIntegerField()
```

And I update the database schema using a migrator like this:

```
new_field = IntegerField(null=True)
migrate(migrator.add_column('repuser', 'abc', new_field))
```

I expected that the model would update its fields to accomodate for the extra field being inserted, but it does not.

For example, this gives a KeyError:

```
model_instance.abc = 42
```

The goal is to be able to dynamically add and remove fields, and have the model update so they can be used.

I found a related question here: [Update existing table/model column/fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44732427/update-existing-table-model-column-fields)

The top answer says the model has to be updated as well after adding fields to the database schema, but I am not sure how to do this, and I can't find related information in the documentation.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It this in Django?

Comment: Nope, it's a python application. Using peewee to work with with SQLite databases.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, in case someone stumbles upon this in the future.

The `Field` base class has an instance method called `add_to_class`, which does exactly what I wanted.

So you can do

```
new_field = SomeField()
new_field.add_to_class(model_class, 'column_name')
```

Note that when you connect to your database, you'll have to get all the columns and add them to your model base manually. I do this right after I connect to the database:

```
for index, column_name in enumerate(database.get_columns('table_name')):
    if (index < 2): # 2 is in my case how many columns I have that are 'static'
        continue
    new_field = SomeField()
    new_field.add_to_class(table_name, column_name)
```

Obviously you'll have to change specifics.

There is no mention of this in the documentation afaik. I literally had to look at the source to find this method.

Sorry if my terminology is a bit wrong, I'm relatively new to python.

Comment: You might be interested in the `playhouse.reflection` extension module, which can dynamically create models from a database schema. http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#reflection

Answer (score 0):

In 3.0a you'll use the `Model._meta.add_field()` method instead:

```
class User(Model):
    pass

f = TextField()
User._meta.add_field('username', f)

print(User._meta.fields)
# {'id': <peewee.AutoField at 0x7f552815bc50>,
#  'username': <peewee.TextField at 0x7f552b1d7e10>}
```